# Spring Integragion + Message Gateway error handling

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a message gateway which is called by a REST controller and I wonder what is the correct approach to handle any errors that might occur on the downstream flow.

What I mean by "handle any errors" is to log some information about them, take some other action whatever that might be, and finally be able to return a 400 to the controller.

For me, the approach that makes more sense is to have an errorChannel on the gateway, BUT I think that a replyChannel might make sense as well.

I've been able to handle the errors with the "errorChannel" approach, don't know if this is the way to go:

```
@MessagingGateway(errorChannel = "integrationFlowErrorChannel")
public interface OrderGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "orders.input")
    void processOrderRequest(Order order);

}
```

Any error sent to the errorChannel are handle by the following service activator:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="integrationFlowErrorChannel")
public void handleExceptions(Message<MessageHandlingException> message) throws RuntimeException {
    log.error(String.format("error: %s", message));
    log.error(String.format("error: %s", message.getPayload()));

    throw new RuntimeException("something bad happened");
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct.

> BUT I think that a replyChannel might make sense as well.

It's not clear what you mean by that; a reply channel is generally not needed unless you want to do something like logging the reply via a wiretap or sending the reply to multiple places.

Comment: One more note: don't use an `errorChannel` name if you have other components which may send to a default global `errorChannel` as well: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/core.html#channel-special-channels. Just use some specific channel for errors exactly in this gateway!

Comment: I get your point, excuse my ignorance. One last question: could I use a Logging Channel Adapter to log the exception instead?

Comment: Artem, Gary, haven't you thought about writing a book on SI? I think all of the books out there are 4 years old and even more.